# How do I draw a point sprite using OpenGL ES on Android?

Tags: opengl, textures, sprites

> **Edit:** I'm using the `GL` enum, which is incorrect since it's not part of OpenGL ES (see my answer). I should have used `GL10`, `GL11` or `GL20` instead.

Here's a few snippets of what I have so far...

```
void create()
{
    renderer = new ImmediateModeRenderer();

    tiles = Gdx.graphics.newTexture(
        Gdx.files.getFileHandle("res/tiles2.png", FileType.Internal),
        TextureFilter.MipMap,
        TextureFilter.Linear,
        TextureWrap.ClampToEdge,
        TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);
}


void render()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.6f, 0.7f, 0.9f, 1);
}

void renderSprite()
{
    int handle = tiles.getTextureObjectHandle();
    Gdx.gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL.GL_POINT_SPRITE);
    Gdx.gl11.glTexEnvi(GL.GL_POINT_SPRITE, GL.GL_COORD_REPLACE, GL.GL_TRUE);

    renderer.begin(GL.GL_POINTS);
    renderer.vertex(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
    renderer.end();
}
```

`create()` is called once when the program starts, and `renderSprites()` is called for each sprite (so, `pos` is unique to each sprite) where the sprites are arranged in a sort-of 3D cube.

Unfortunately though, this just renders a few white dots...

[image: Point sprite problem]

I suppose that the texture isn't being bound which is why I'm getting white dots. Also, when I draw my sprites on anything other than 0 z-axis, they do not appear -- I read that I need to crease my zfar and znear, but I have no idea how to do this using libgdx (perhaps it's because I'm using ortho projection? What do I use instead?).

I know that the texture is usable, since I was able to render it using a SpriteBatch, but  I guess I'm not using it properly with OpenGL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer, here's how you render textured point sprites, using alpha test and depth test:

```
create()
{
    renderer = new ImmediateModeRenderer();

    tiles = Gdx.graphics.newTexture(
        Gdx.files.internal("data/tiles2.png"),
        TextureFilter.MipMap,
        TextureFilter.Linear,
        TextureWrap.ClampToEdge,
        TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.6f, 0.7f, 0.9f, 1);

    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);

    Gdx.gl10.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_GREATER, 0);

    Gdx.gl11.glTexEnvi(
        GL11.GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES, 
        GL11.GL_COORD_REPLACE_OES,
        GL11.GL_TRUE);

    Gdx.gl10.glPointSize(s);

    tiles.bind();
}

render()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.begin(GL10.GL_POINTS);

    // render 3 point sprites at various 3d points
    renderer.vertex(-.1f, 0, -.1f);
    renderer.vertex(0, 0, 0);
    renderer.vertex(.1f, 0, .1f);

    // ... more vertices here if needed (one for each sprite) ...

    renderer.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using orthogonal projection, then chances are you called `Gdx.gl.glOrtho()` at some point. The last two arguments are your near and far distances.

By the way, you should call `Gdx.gl.glClearColor()` *before* `Gdx.gl.glClear()`. It's not dramatic in your code, you will only get the first frame wrong, but be careful about similar errors.